# give a background color to the pointer of popover bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to give a background colour to the pointing element of a popover. How can I do so? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/achal_arcane/u20n5faq/22/) for the code

```
.popover{
   background:rgba(128, 21, 21,0.8);
   font-weight: bold;
   border-radius: 2%;
}
.popover-body{
   background:rgba(128, 21, 21,0.8);
   color: #ffffff;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Without code we can't help you, Please add code into snippet.

Comment: Come on add a jsfiddle

Comment: sorry I am new to stack overflow. jsfiddle added

Comment: Why is this getting down voted? It the question seems clear and the image shows chat the problem is. Even with a nice little MS paint circle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Custom color popover

After taking a look at bootstrap v4.1.3 css file:

The css your searching for is `.popover .arrow::after` css rule.
But changing this will change all popovers on your site.
So we want to choose the ones we select with a custom class. `.custom` in the example.

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  let e = $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover().data('bs.popover').getTipElement();
  console.log(e);
  $(e).addClass("custom");
});
```

```css
.popover {}

.custom .popover-body {
  background-color: red;
}

.custom .popover-header {
  background-color: darkred;
}

.custom .arrow {}

.custom.popover .arrow::after {
  border-right-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger custom" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

So the explanation is:

- Use javascript to add a class to the popover (class is "custom" in exaple above)
- Add your own css rules with higher specificity.
- Remember to the correct styles. (its a css triangle)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.  Example of css triangle helped me in understanding the problem.

Comment: @AchalGupta yeah i was considering linking it. I'll do it here for others to find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work

Answer (score 0):

If it's bootstrap tooltip pls try code i written below

```
.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow {
    border-top-color: #870a17; /* or what ever color you want*/
}
```

but it will work only if it's bootstrap tooltip with top option if anything else you should have to give code.

Answer (score 0):

If it is bootstrap then please search in CSS. There must be present class like `.bs-popover-top .arrow::before`.

Make changes in it or you can write your own similarly like below.[note : you can change class name as per your code]

> .bs-popover-top .arrow::before{
>   border-top-color:#f00;
>   }